# How to use if-else or switch operator in Assembly?

Tags: if-statement, assembly, switch-statement

How do I use multiple if-else statements or the switch operator from C/C++ in Assembly?

Something like this in C:

```
if ( number == 2 )
  printf("TWO");
else if ( number == 3 )
  printf("THREE");
else if ( number == 4 )
  printf("FOUR");
```

Or using switch:

```
switch (i)
     {
        case 2:
           printf("TWO"); break;
        case 3:
           printf("THREE"); break;
        case 4:
           printf("FOUR"); break;
     }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not create a C program containing the statements, build it, and look at the generated assembler code? [Here's a good online resource](https://godbolt.org) to do it.

Comment: Generally, you use conditional jumps to transfer control appropriately.  The specifics would depend on the particular architecture you have in mind.

Comment: Those two pieces of code are not equivalent, the `switch` has fallthrough so eg for i==2, all prints will be executed.

Comment: Do you know how to do a single if-then?  If not, then learn that first. There's a lot of detail in that alone (like reversing the condition), and it extrapolates to the others.

Comment: There may be cases where a switch statement could more efficiently be done as a jump table. The value of with switch variable would act as an index into a jump table.

Answer (score 0):

Architecture is critical for specifics but here's some psuedo code which does what you want.

```
... # your code
jmp SWITCH

OPTION1:
... # do option 1
jmp DONE
OPTION2:
... # do option 2
jmp DONE
Option3:
... # do option 3
jmp DONE

SWITCH:
if opt1:
jmp OPTION1
if opt2:
jmp OPTION2
if opt3:
jmp OPTION3

DONE:
... #continue your program
```

Answer (score 0):

A detailed answer will depend upon the particular machine instruction set for which you are writing the assembly language.  Basically you write assembly code to perform the C language series of tests (if statements) and branches.

In pseudo-assembly it might look like this:

```
load  r1, number            // load the value of number into register 1
cmpi r1, 2                  // compare register 1 to the immediate value 2
bne  test_for_3             // branch to label "test_for_3" if the compare results is not equal
call printf                 // I am ignoring the parameter passing here
...                         // but this is where the code goes to handle
...                         // the case where number == 2
branch the_end              // branch to the label "the_end"
test_for_3:                 // labels the instruction location (program counter)
                            // such that branch instructions can reference it
cmpi r1, 3                  // compare register 1 to immediate value 3
bne  test_for_4             // branch if not equal to label "test_for_4"
...                         // perform printf "THREE"
branch the_end              // branch to the label "the_end"
test_for_4:                 // labels the instruction location for above branch
cmpi r1, 4                  // compare register 1 to immediate value 4
bne the_end                 // branch if not equal to label "the_end"
...                         // perform printf "FOUR"
the_end:                    // labels the instruction location following your 3 test for the value of number
```